# Custom video source for WebRTC on Android

Tags: java, android, streaming, webrtc, webrtc-android

### Overview

I would like to use a custom video source to live stream video via WebRTC Android implementation. If I understand correctly, existing implementation only supports front and back facing cameras on Android phones. The following classes are relevant in this scenario:

- [Camera1Enumerator.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/Camera1Enumerator.java)
- [VideoCapturer.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/VideoCapturer.java)
- [PeerConnectionFactory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/PeerConnectionFactory.java)
- [VideoSource.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/VideoSource.java)
- [VideoTrack.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/VideoTrack.java)

Currently for using front facing camera on Android phone I'm doing the following steps:

```
CameraEnumerator enumerator = new Camera1Enumerator(false);
VideoCapturer videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false);
videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, this.getApplicationContext(), videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
VideoTrack localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(VideoTrackID, videoSource);
```

### My scenario

I've a callback handler that receives video buffer in byte array from custom video source:

```
public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {}
```

How would I be able to send this byte array buffer? I'm not sure about the solution, but I think I would have to implement custom `VideoCapturer`?

#### Existing questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654425/create-a-webrtc-videotrack-with-a-custom-capturer-on-android-with-libjingle) might be relevant, though I'm not using libjingle library, only native WebRTC Android package.

Similar questions/articles:

- [for iOS platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493923/how-to-custom-webrtc-video-source) but unfortunately I couldn't help with the answers.
- [for native C++ platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131317/custom-video-capture-native-webrtc)
- [article about native implementation](https://sourcey.com/articles/webrtc-custom-opencv-video-capture)

Comment: You want to stream a video file to WebRTC (like fake person in chat video? just for the example) or broadcast an exiting broadcaster ? do you need it as android app ? if I will provide a way to hook an exiting app ? is android tag related ? because you provided source code from chromium

Comment: I want to stream an existing video source, for which I receive data via `onReceive` method. I will need to handle it inside Android app, as the device is connected to the phone via USB cable. Source code is hosted on chromium, but it's for Android app. It seems that the whole WebRTC project is hosted there.

Comment: Please explain, you want to stream an existing video source to where ? you receive bytes from a URL for  example, your android phone decrypt them and so you will see them as frames, where do you want to send them ?

Comment: @JimWest it's a P2P connection using WebRTC. It's not an issue of streaming to the client on the other side, it's an issue with WebRTC Java implementation apparently not supporting external video source for processing apart from existing front/back cameras.

Comment: you want to stream a local video instead of camera to a running video chat ? it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @whoopdedoo , Yes I want to stream a local video instead of a camera to a running video chat. correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Implement custom `VideoCapturer` and create `VideoFrame` using `byte[]` stream data in `onReceive` handler. There actually exists a very good example of [FileVideoCapturer](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/webrtc/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/FileVideoCapturer.java), which implements `VideoCapturer`.
2. Simply construct `VideoFrame` from [NV21Buffer](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/webrtc/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/NV21Buffer.java), which is created from our byte array stream data. Then we only need to use our previously created `VideoSource` to capture this frame. Example:

```
public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size, int width, int height) {
    long timestampNS = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    NV21Buffer buffer = new NV21Buffer(videoBuffer, width, height, null);

    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(buffer, 0, timestampNS);
    videoSource.getCapturerObserver().onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);

    videoFrame.release();
}
```

Comment: A bit late to the party, but can you elaborate? The onReceive(byte[],int,int,int) is not the onReceive from DJI from my understanding. So which event is this?

Comment: I mean the onReceive event from DJI does not provide width and height, so I have a hard time following where you obtained those from all of the sudden.